# How to count 0's OR 1's in binary number without knowing which beforehand

Tags: assembly, mips, bitmask

I'm working in assembly (MIPS32) and need to count the number of 0's *OR* 1's based on user decision. (i.e. I don't know which beforehand)

The program is required to execute topdown such that no control flow is allowed.

**Example1**:

binary repr of number: `00001010`

user choice: `0`

answer: `6`

**Example2**:

binary repr of number: `00001010`

user choice: `1`

answer: `2`

I understand how to use a bitmask to count the total of either if I know which one beforehand. However, I'm totally lost in how to approach getting the count of either w/o knowing which beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

So let's say you know how to count the number of 0s.  One approach is that, if the user wants 1s, you complement (bitwise NOT) the number before counting the 0s.

One way to accomplish the latter is by XOR with -1 (in two's complement representation, so that it's all 1s).  If you negate the user's choice of 0 or 1, you get 0 or -1, and XOR with 0 doesn't affect a number.  So in C this could look like

`result = count_zeros(number ^ -choice)`

I don't know the MIPS instruction set so I'll leave it to you to write this in assembly.

(If this is for an assignment, remember to cite this answer in your submission.)

Comment: Or you can do the work ahead of time, `ones_count = popcount(number)`, then after the user's choice do `32-ones_count` or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I considered that, but it's not so convenient to do it without branches, as the OP requires.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that being a requirement.  There is a trick for 31-count for count 0..31:  `count ^= 31`, which you could do branchlessly but still less conveniently.  (GCC uses this trick to flip x86 `bsr` results into clz).  But that doesn't help for `32-count`.  Of course, MIPS4 and later have `movz` / `movn` conditional move based on another register being 0 or non-zero, making this easy.  clang compiles branchlessly for `return ones ? x : 32-x;` https://godbolt.org/z/ThTMMc.  But yes, if you're not optimizing for latency from ones to result, then your way is good and simple.